# select2 AJAX'd to a model, configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jquery, jquery-select2

So, I just discovered [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).  Awesome.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to use it, server side with ajax / json.  All of the examples I see, everywhere, show using select2 with JSONP to retrieve data from an external source.  I feel like this should be even easier if calling from a local model, no?  I'll get right to the nitty gritty.  json returns a value, but the searchbox doesn't autocomplete, it stays blank.

view html:

```
<%= form_tag request_pal_path, remote: true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'ui-corner-all' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Send request", class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

and calling some js on it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#find_user #email").select2({
    width: '400px',
    placeholder: "Find user...",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    multiple: false,
    id: function(obj) {
      return obj.id; // use slug field for id
    },
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
      url: "/users",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term, // search term
          page_limit: 10
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
        return {results: data};
      }
    },
    formatResult: FormatResult,
    formatSelection: FormatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
  });

})

function FormatResult(user) {
  return '<div>' + user.name + '</div>';
}

function FormatSelection(user) {
  return user.name;
}
```

which goes to the controller, `user index action`:

```
def index
  @find = User.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
  @users = @find.where('id NOT IN (?)', current_user.id).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per(100)
  @title = "Potential pals"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {
      @find = @find
      @users = @users
    }
    format.json { @find }
  end
end
```

and I made a .json file for it to respond to (not sure if this is even necessary):

```
<% @find.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

So, the json is working, to an extent.  If I look in the developer console, it shows a response coming from `http://localhost:3000/users.json?q=tay`, or whereever, and it returns a single value, for `Taylor` (in that instance).  But when I search inside of the select2 search box, it just spins and spins, with no results.  No console errors, so that's nice, ha.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in your .json file, since select2 needs json array or json object. Try to remove it and respond with `format.json { render json: @find.to_json }`. Other code seems ok to me.

Comment: this gives me an error regarding the template missing.  `Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: *`

Comment: this did it, actually!  I went with a combination of the two of you... `format.json { render json: @find }`.  I was so close, lol.

Comment: Yes, I forgot `render json:`, sorry. Glad you succeeded.

Comment: 1 more question, if you don't mind.  I'm trying to render a partial through JS at the same time (to load the user pictures in a separate window).  I added `$('#user_index').html("<%= j render partial: 'users/index' %>");` to the `results` section of the ajax (partial is just `<%= render @users if @users %>`.  That works, in that it loads the text in quotes into that div.  Obviously that's not the behavior I'm after.  I tried putting it in my view in `script` tags, but it then loads nothing (it clears out the div).  Do you know a way to better handle that?

Comment: Calling `j render partial:` in `results` has no meaning since it's ruby code and it's what you should do in your rails app, not on the client side. Maybe you should add action to `UsersController`, for instance `pictures`, and make new ajax request to this action after select2 ajax request suceeded. In this action `respond_to {|format| format.js }` and in `pictures.js.erb` put your current code `$('#user_index').html("<%= j render partial: 'users/index' %>");`. I t should work like you expect.

Comment: Or there is other way - to achieve this through select2 response `results`, but it seems to me that it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The select2 plugin expects JSON data in the following format:

```
[ { "text": "Taylor", "id": 1 }, { "text" : "Tailor", "id": 2 }, ...]
```

So you need to replace `name` with `text` in your user model when converting to JSON:

```
def as_json(*args)
    super.tap { |hash| hash["text"] = hash.delete "name" }
end
```

and then in the index method:

```
def index
  @find = User.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
  @users = @find.where('id NOT IN (?)', current_user.id).order('random()').page(params[:page]).per(100)
  @title = "Potential pals"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {
      @find = @find
      @users = @users
    }
    format.json { render json: @find, :only => [:text, :id] }  # might be :name here ?
  end
end
```

and you don't need the view for JSON.

Comment: select2 expects `{id: ..., text: ...}` format only if you use default implementation of formatResult, if you use your own function, you can supply any format you would like.

Comment: yeah, didn't have to do all that, but the `render` was the ticket.  thanks!  have an upvote =)